# What should I do if I would like to convert such a php system to C#?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, webmatrix

I have been developing a php web system for my project and I have completed the PHP v system however, my lecturer refuse to mark it and say that I should use C# with web matrix instead of php and MySQL with dreamweaver. Now That i have completed the assignment but in a different format I would like to ask if there is any way to do changes to the scripts instead of redoing the whole project.

Another thing is that in my PHP system, I have pages like:

login.php > login_now.php > home.php

where login_now.php is the processor page.

Does C# allows me to have a processor page similar to this as well?

If don't mind can someone advice me on what I should do? Thanks so much...I am lost.

Answer (score 1):

Your only option is to rewrite the application from the ground up. The migration assistant mentioned by Luxspes is virtually useless as it was written for .NET v 1.1 (Web Forms), whereas the Web Pages framework runs on v 4.0.

You can use "processor" pages in Web Pages in the same way as you have in PHP, but my preference would be house the processing logic in the same page as the form and then redirect on success using the Post - Redirect - Get pattern (PRG), regardless of whether I was using PHP or ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If what to you need is to make it run on .NET, you could use PHP .NET Compiler: Phalanger: http://www.php-compiler.net/

If you want to actually translate the code you could use this: http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived-v11/migration-assistants/php-to-aspnet

Comment: ASP.NET is a container term for web based programming using a .NET language, C# is one of the .NET languages you can use to program asp.net